# Java: Reading the incoming sms messages from a phone connected to PC over USB (from the PC side)

Tags: java, android, sms

I'd like to intercept SMS messages from an Android phone connected to PC over USB. Java app on PC side.

Where should I start? Would it be apps on both sides? Or is there some PC-side lib for that?

I've only found tips for serial port access like SmsJ.

Answer (score 7):

Background :

When you attach phone with USB cable, your computer creates a virtual COMM Port and a new port number is assign to it. You can see the port number detail in Device Manager List.

Development Part:

For the starting you can read the [Java's Port reading example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/PortReader.htm). Just study this example and you will be able to connect and send SMS from your android phone. It will allow to fire you command in Computer that will actually goes to attached Phone. For sending command to COMM Port you will be requiring [AT Commands to Send SMS](http://www.smssolutions.net/tutorials/gsm/sendsmsat/). Using AT Commands, you will also be able to read SMS and perform other functions on the phone.

You can also connect your phone through bluetooth, It will also assign same virtual COMM Port and you can do all functionality as well.